# Error 1265 Data truncated when Importing with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, truncate

*Using MySQL workbench Version 8.0.26 on Windows 10, on a local connection.*

Ok, so I'm importing data from a .csv using LOAD DATA INFILE, and it gets stuck at the first row (error 1265, column "delivery_cost" truncated etc.) and I do not understand why. Can somebody explain how this works?

LOADing code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/receipts.csv'
INTO TABLE receipts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
order_id,
order_date,
customer_id,
delivery_date,
total_order,
delivery_fee,
payment_method, 
delivery_cost
)
```

This is how my column is structured:

`delivery_cost DOUBLE (10,2) DEFAULT 0`

.csv looks like this (delivery_cost is the last one, header not included to save space):

```
1,2021-10-07,771,2021-10-08,150,6,1,6.0
2,2021-10-07,865,2021-10-08,29300,0,2,27.0
3,2021-10-07,823,2021-10-09,14200,0,4,13.0
```

The data type & size looks fine. I even replaced the NULL default with 0. Changing the number of digits from DOUBLE makes no difference [ DOUBLE(10,2) to DOUBLE(10,1) or (10.3) ].

It works when I'm using SET = FLOOR(@delivery_cost) to get only the whole number. It works when I'm using SET delivery_cost = @delivery_cost -0.5 (for some reason), and funny enough it works when I'm using SET delivery_cost = @delivery_cost -0.5 + 0.5 (so I get the exact same number that I want to import). Actually it works even with SET delivery_cost = @delivery_cost + 0.

I am extremely confused about why is this. I guess it's no big deal because I found a workaround, but I want to understand the root cause. Note: This is my first StackOverflow post and I'm new to programming (SQL is my first language). Ty <3

Comment: Check: `For a text file generated on a Windows system, proper file reading might require LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator.`, see [LOAD DATA Statement :: Field and Line Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling).

Comment: Uuu, you're right. I found this thread explaining it further [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462615/what-do-the-following-mysql-csv-import-query-terms-mean). Thank you @wchiquito!

Comment: That did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the comment by wchiquito. Needs "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'"